# While using pytest in pycharm IDE, I am unable to see the run button

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pytest, pylint

Currently I am working in pytest and I have written some class with function in some py file as well i have one more file in which I have written only function in other py file.

I am attaching the image to make it more clear. I have highlighted it with yellow color

[image: Class with test function]

Now I am attaching other image which doesn't have any class defined. Only some functions has been defined in this test file. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

So my concern is if I want to run any particular function (without any class defined), how its possible. As per my understanding that green color run symbol should come in 2nd image as well before every test function. So is there any IDE setting issue or something else. I have pytest install, pylint install. Does this VCS configuration issue (VCS I mean path of the project).

Any leads to fix this issue.

Comment: The first one are run by `unittest`, the second by `pytest`. You should be able the select "Run tests with unittest" / "Run test with pytest" in the context menu. You cannot "run" these functions, they have to be run by pytest.

Comment: How is the file with pytest tests called? Try switching default test runner to pytest in **Settings -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools -> Testing -> pytest**. I believe `pytest` can handle unittest-styled tests as well.

Answer (score 0):

For those stumbling upon this issue now 3+ years later, you need to check two settings:

- Settings > Tools > Python Integrated Tools > Testing > pytest (as pointed out by Pavel in the comments)
- Settings > Editor > General > Gutter Icons